# Remover Filas Duplicadas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla que esta conformada por las columnas del listado, lo que necesito es eliminar los registros duplicados cosniderando que es duplicado cuando la información de todas las columnas de un registro es igual a la información de todas las columnas de otro registro.

```
[Block ID],[Auditor Id],[Auditor],[Factory ID],[Store],[Supervisor],[Alert Id],[Alert Type],[Alert Date],[Alert Date (TimeStamp)],[Alert Description],[Details],[Status],[Severity],[Server Date],[Server TimeStamp],[Alert Closed Date],[Alert Closed (TimeStamp)],[Alert Duration],[Comments],[Alert Updated By],[City],[Province],[Country Id],[Postal Code],[Alert Source],[Activity Code],[CDAR Store Id],[Alert Cycle],[Display Alert],[Low Limit],[Upper Limit],[ZScore],[Additional Info],[Image Url],[Alert Validation],[Alert Duration (Net)],[Alert Reason],[Accuracy],[Cont By Phone],[Cont By Chat],[Executive Name],[RMS Resource ID],[Alert Pushed Time],[LOB],[Collection Type],[Project],[Alert Chat],[Chat Image],[Store Type],[Chatbot Status],[Frequency],[Audit Id],[Closed by AQCT],[Store Export User Date],[Store export User TimeStamp],[Store Export System Date],[Store export System TimeStamp],[Country]
```

Usando esto logro determinar cuales son los registros duplicados, adicionalmente no tiene u ID Unico que me ayude a trabajar este tema

```
SELECT [Block ID]
      ,[Auditor Id]
      ,[Auditor]
    .
    .
    .
      ,Store export User TimeStamp]
      ,[Store Export System Date]
      ,[Store export System TimeStamp]
      ,[Country]
    ,COUNT(*)
  FROM [dbo].[PE_Acumulado]
  GROUP BY [Block ID]
      ,[Auditor Id]
      ,[Auditor]
    .
    .
    .
      ,Store export User TimeStamp]
      ,[Store Export System Date]
      ,[Store export System TimeStamp]
      ,[Country]
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar las ventajas que permiten usar los CTE (Common Table Expression o Expresiones comunes de tabla) como vistas actualizables que permiten modificar los datos a las tablas que apuntan.

El código es simple. Se enumeran las filas por grupos y solo mantenemos la fila con valor 1 de cada grupo. No mencionas el orden, pero puedes ajustar la consulta para definir mejor cual fila vas a mantener.

```
WITH Duplicados AS(
SELECT *
    ,COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY [Block ID]
                                ,[Auditor Id]
                                ,[Auditor]
                                ,[Store export User TimeStamp]
                                ,[Store Export System Date]
                                ,[Store export System TimeStamp]
                                ,[Country]
                    ORDER BY [Block ID]) fila --Cambiar por algo relevante en caso de existir
  FROM [dbo].[PE_Acumulado]
)
--SELECT * --Para ver que filas se eliminarán
DELETE FROM Duplicados
WHERE rn > 1;
```